# ginput from matplotlib in JupyterLab does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ginput

According to
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-ginput-in-python/ the ginput function in Python is given by the following code:

```
%matplotlib widget 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(10)
   
plt.plot(t, np.sin(t))
     
plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.ginput()\
 function Example', fontweight ="bold")
   
print("After 3 clicks :")
x = plt.ginput(3)
print(x)
   
plt.show()
```

The only modification for jupyterlab that I inserted is the magic function

```
%matplotlib widget
```

at the beginning of the script. However, I do not get ginput() to work in Jupyterlab. It does not yield any errors, just no Figure appears, where I could click with the mouse. The output of ginput() accordingly is empty. In other Python IDE's, it works flawlessly (e.g. Thonny).

**Did anybody get the ginput() function to work in Jupyterlab?**

Comment: Yes. Use `%matplotlib qt`: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC6Ei.png)

Comment: That seems like a bug in ipympl.  I would report it to them (if it has not already been reported).